# Twitter oAuth - Request tokens

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/ to use twitter on a wordpress blog. But I've a problem with request tokens.

Here's my code:

```
$to = new TwitterOAuth($options['consumer_key'], $options['consumer_secret']);
$tok = $to->getRequestToken();


function getRequestToken() {
    $r = $this->oAuthRequest($this->requestTokenURL());
    $token = $this->oAuthParseResponse($r);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
}
```

But after clicking on the sign in button, Twitter returns this:

'Whoa there!
There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account.'

The URL is https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=

Presumably the missing value is the problem.

I'm hoping to then allow the logged in user to tweet from the site, yet I haven't even gone near that with the above problem.

Any ideas??

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your twitter app settings page.

Comment: @AlphaMale http://imgur.com/tKPF0

Comment: the sign in using twitter button is at hopeish.com/wordpress/wp-login.php

Comment: Sir, screenshot of OAuth tab please..

Comment: @AlphaMale the file?? Oauth.php??

Comment: NO... The screenshot you've currently attached is of seetings tab. take screenshot of Oauth tab in app settings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12798/discussion-between-backslap-search-engine-and-alphamale)

Answer (score 0):

Haves you tried logging into Twitters Developer site (https://dev.twitter.com/) to get your access token? If not you need to create an app which will allow access from your site to twiiter. The Directions on the developer site are pretty easy to follow.